# python3 class argument error

Tags: python, class, python-3.5

I m trying to create a class in python 3.5
here is the class file

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from threading import Thread

class perstrans:
    def __init__(self,a,img,s):
        self.name=a
        self.imx = img.shape[1]
        self.imy = img.shape[0]
        self.src = np.float32(
            [[28, 198], [252, 198], [203, 140], [79, 141]],
            [[28, 198], [252, 198], [203, 140], [79, 141]])
        self.dst = np.float32(
            [[0, imy],
             [imx, imy],
             [imx, 0],
             [0, 0]])
        self.pmat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(self.src[s[1]], self.dst)
        return None
    def transfer(self,image):
        Thread(target=self.perstr, args=(image)).start()

    def perstr(self,imaga):
        self.h, self.w = imaga.shape[:2]
        self.res = cv2.warpPerspective(imaga, m, (w,h), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        return self

    def getres(self):
        return self.res
```

But when i initialize it like here i get the following error

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import perstrans
cap = WebcamVideoStream(0).start()
img = cap.read()   
img = cv2.resize(img,(resizex,resizey))
h, w = img.shape[:2]
trns=perstrans.perstrans("angle",img,0)
....


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    trns=perstrans.perstrans("angle",img,0)
  File "/home/huzeyfe/Desktop/robotaksi data/line tracking/duzenlenmis/v2/perstrans.py", line 12, in __init__
    [[28, 198], [252, 198], [203, 140], [79, 141]])
TypeError: function takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Thanks

Note: This question might be duplicate but most of the questions i saw there was  the self missing in function decleration and i couldnt find anything like mine

Comment: `np.float32()` simply doesn't take two separate lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with classes. You are simply trying to pass two separate arguments to `np.float32()`:

```
np.float32(
    [[28, 198], [252, 198], [203, 140], [79, 141]],
    [[28, 198], [252, 198], [203, 140], [79, 141]])
```

Look closely. That's two times the list `[[28, 198], [252, 198], [203, 140], [79, 141]]`. `np.float32()` only takes a *single* argument.

Correct that line to pass in *one* argument.

Not that your code will work after that; there are more problems:

- `s` is being treated as something that can be indexed in your class `__init__` method:

  ```
  self.pmat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(self.src[s[1]], self.dst)
  #                                                ^^^^
  ```

  note the `s[1]`, but your *use* of the class passes in a single integer value for `s`:

  ```
  trns=perstrans.perstrans("angle",img,0)
  #                                    ^
  ```

  so `s[1]` will fail too, with `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.
- you are passing in just the image as the `args` argument for `Thread()`; the parentheses do not make this a tuple:

  ```
  Thread(target=self.perstr, args=(image)).start()
  #                               ^^^^^^^
  ```

  You'll need to add a comma there, or you'll get more errors (exactly what depends on the type of the object referenced by `image`):

  ```
  Thread(target=self.perstr, args=(image,)).start()
  ```